# mixing content of DNA (list) in R

Tags: r, dna-sequence

I have a list of DNA sequences and I want to mix the contents.
Let's say `dna_lst:`

```
[1] AATTAATTCC
[2] ATCGATCG
[3] TTTAACCCCCGG
```

I want to generate mix dna content like:`dna_mix:`

```
[1] TACAATTACT
[2] CATGCTAG
[3] CCTGATCTCGAC
```

how can I do this in R?
thanks.

Comment: Is the mixing is random?

Comment: @DavidArenburg yes, randomly mix. but it must keep the ratio of contents.

Comment: Not sure what's ratio of contents. Also, what is the class of your data set

Comment: @DavidArenburg, for example if I have 3 of A and 1 of C&G like `AAACG`. I want to generate sth like `ACAGA` so I have still 3A and one C&G. my data is a list including factors.

Comment: in other words, you just want a permutation of your sequences... Both answers below do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that :

```
dna_mix<-sapply(dna_lst,function(dna){paste(sample(strsplit(dna,"")[[1]]),collapse="")})
```

can work if what you want is a "random mixing"

```
> dna_mix
    AATTAATTCC       ATCGATCG   TTTAACCCCCGG 
  "TTTATCAAAC"     "TAACCGGT" "CTACTCACGGTC"
```

with a list of factor (if each sequence is an element of the list) :

```
lapply(dna_lst,function(dna){paste(sample(strsplit(as.character(dna),"")[[1]]),collapse="")})
```

should work.

Comment: recieving error: `Error in strsplit(dna, ""): non-character argument`. my dataset is a factor.

Comment: @Cina, could you edit your question and put your data exactly as it is ? That would be easier to answer the right way. As it is, it looks like a character vector to me... (output of dput(dna_lst) would be fine)

Comment: @Cina, is it ok with the `lapply` version ? It would really help to know how your list is built (one sequence per element ? one element with all 3 sequences ? ...)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(dna_lst), ""), function(x) paste(sample(x), collapse = ""))
```

Comment: I receive error `Error in sapply(strsplit(dna_lst, ""), function(x) paste(sample(x), collapse = "")) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'X' in selecting a method for function 'sapply': Error in strsplit(dna, "") : non-character argument` I am using list of factors. my dataset is huge. I convert to character and again the same error